# Loading mat files within a package function

Tags: package, octave

I'm working on an package for GNU Octave.  One of the package functions uses a large, pre-computed table of data. That data is stored in a mat file which I load and unload when the function is called.  The problem is that I'm unsure of a good, installation non-specific way of doing this.  As near as I can tell I have to give the load command an absolute path to the mat file within the package install directory.  I can see no way of getting that directory at run-time. Am I missing something or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKG_ADD is executed when the package is loaded so you can get the path where PKG_ADD resides in with `__fqp__ = fileparts (mfilename ("fullpath"));`From there you can init your data.

If you want the install dir from another package it's possible to `load( pkg ("local_list"))` and inspect `local_packages`.

I also think such specific Octave questions should go to the help@octave.org mailinglist.

Do you want to distribute your new package on octave-forge?

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for. Thanks. I'm considering octave-forge, yes, but I'm not committed to it just yet.